# Is it still necessary to use packages T1 and utf8 in editor TeXstudio?

Tags: unicode, font-encodings

I have an old TEX file where we used

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I figured out form [here](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/symbols/) that T1 is needed for  |, < and >.
But do I still need `utf8`? I am on windows, I use TeXstudio and it seems, I don't need it - all Umlaute are displayed correctly.

Comment: For utf8, you don't: it's now the default for latex.

Comment: I tend to still add `utf8` in case I need to send the tex code to someone who haven't updated their latex installation in a while.

Comment: texstudio is not relevant that is just the editor you use to write the file. For pdflatex you should still specify T1 font encoding, declaring utf8 input doesn't matter as it is the default anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A short writeup of the comments

- if you use `pdflatex` `T1` with `fontenc` is still relevant for better use of the fonts.
- as for `utf8` it is now the default has has been for some time, so you ought to be able to drop it. Personally I tend to add it anyways just as a reminder (some editors actually scans the preamble) but also if the document later on might be sent to others where you don't know if they are using an older latex installation (that might for example be arXiv).